# I have done crosstabs and a Correspondence Analysis, having trouble reporting and interpreting Chi-Squared and Inertia?

Tags: chi-squared-test, correspondence-analysis

I have data on 1500 cases with two variables (color, genus) with 5 colors and 6 genera. I almost had generally equal spread across genus, but one is disproportionately represented and has about twice as many cases as the other 5. Eyeballing the data, it is clear that within each genus, cases tend to be overwhelmingly one color or one of two colors, with a minority being the rest. Plus, within color groups, there tends to be a dramatic difference between the genus that have a high count and those that don't. It is clear that there are strong associations. That's as far as my brain gets me, but I did crosstabs and correspondence analysis and got a summary table and I am a bit lost on how to interpret it. I've read a few papers trying to explain what's going on but am still getting confused.

[image: Summary Table]

I need to report the inertia and chi-squared values and interpret them both. I can report Chi-Squared: (20, N=1500) = 941.653, p<0.001.

1) Is this right? I think it is based on my reading but I might be wrong.

2) How do I report Inertia? I'm not sure I fully understand how Inertia works because I have two values for it, Inertia in the third column and then again with Proportion of Inertia Accounted for, and these numbers are different. The first one adds up to .628 and the second to 1.000

3) And how am I meant to interpret Chi-Squared other than that it is high? What is high meant to be relative to?

4) How do I interpret Inertia and which Inertia value am I looking at?

Answer (score 0):

The summary table supports that most of the variation is in the first dimension. Correspondence analysis is often best reported on visually, with biplots. Some examples in

- [How variables (constrained loadings) are selected in a biplot CCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297021/how-variables-constrained-loadings-are-selected-in-a-biplot-cca)
- [Interpreting biplots in correspondence analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197740/interpreting-biplots-in-correspondence-analysis)
- [Interpreting 2D correspondence analysis plots (Part II)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3287/interpreting-2d-correspondence-analysis-plots-part-ii)
  Some theory
- [PCA and Correspondence analysis in their relation to Biplot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141754/pca-and-correspondence-analysis-in-their-relation-to-biplot)